# Zoom SKSpriteNode in/out towards direction of point (pinch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, zooming

I have a Spritekit game, and an SKSpriteNode (mapContainer) which is the map, and that map is inside another SKSpriteNode (rightCon) which is its container. When pinching in/out I want to zoom in/out on the map.

I've found code online and managed to get something that seems to work, but it's not quite right.

The issue is that as soon as I start the pinch it jumps a little (by that, I mean, the map noticeably shifts position rather than moving smoothly) , and then it zooms in/out smoothly towards the pinch. And I'm not sure why.

```
- (void)rightConPTZ:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];

    CGPoint pointInMap = [rightCon convertPoint:touchLocation fromNode:self];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        float scale = recognizer.scale-lastScale;

        mapContainer.xScale += scale;
        mapContainer.yScale += scale;

        float centerX = 0;
        float centerY = 0;

        float offsetToCenterX = centerX-pointInMap.x;
        float offsetToCenterY = centerY-pointInMap.y;

        float multiX = offsetToCenterX*mapContainer.xScale;
        float multiY = offsetToCenterY*mapContainer.xScale; //xscale & yscale are the same (and always will be)

        float zoomInFactor = 2;

        float scaleDiff = (zoomInFactor - mapContainer.xScale) / (zoomInFactor - 1.0f);

        float multiX2 = offsetToCenterX*scaleDiff;
        float multiY2 = offsetToCenterY*scaleDiff;

        float subX = multiX-multiX2;
        float subY = multiY-multiY2;

        mapContainer.position = CGPointMake(subX, subY);

        lastScale = recognizer.scale;
    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        lastScale = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what the problem might be? Is there a mistake in the code, or have I (as I suspect) left some important part out of this equation for smooth zooming towards the pinch?